# Why is this custom spacemacs major mode keybinding not working?

Tags: spacemacs

In `.spacemacs` I am trying to define a few custom, major mode mappings, that can be accesed using `SPC m`. This is working fine for `org-mode`:

```
  (evil-leader/set-key-for-mode 'org-mode "l" 'org-insert-link)
```

but when I define it for a different mode it doesn't work:

```
  (evil-leader/set-key-for-mode 'sclang-mode "sl" 'sclang-eval-line)
```

Using `SPC m`  just returns `SPC m is undefined`

**UPDATE:**

The mode is part of a package that I used following [these instructions](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/supercollider-with-emacs-on-osx/). In my .spacemacs file I have added these lines to make it work:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/sc/el")
(require 'sclang)
(setenv "PATH" (concat (getenv "PATH") ":/Applications/SuperCollider/SuperCollider.app/Contents/Resources"))
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("/Applications/SuperCollider"  "/Applications/SuperCollider/SuperCollider.app/Contents/Resources" )))
```

It also required to move a folder in the `.emacs.d` folder (and I need to remove it temporarily before every `spacemacs` update...) so yes, definitely not even close to an official layer.

Comment: Can you use set-key-for-mode to bind multi-key combos? Does "sl" work in org-mode, or does it only work for single keys?

Comment: @Tyler You are right `sl` is not working in `org-mode` either. Nevertheless even when I put just `l` for `sclang-mode` I get `SPC m is undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this with help from the Spacemacs Gitter channel.

There was a deeper issue with the definition of the major mode itself. More specifically (quoting NJBS's answer on Gitter):

> Your issue is that sclang-mode doesn't define itself properly by
>   deriving from fundamental-mode, but rather it defines itself using
>   defun. You can change sclang-mode.el's mode definition to the
>   following and your bindings should stick:
>
> ```
> (define-derived-mode sclang-mode fundamental-mode "sclang-mode"
>   "Major mode for editing SuperCollider language code.
> \\{sclang-mode-map}
> "
>   (sclang-mode-set-local-variables)
>   (sclang-set-font-lock-keywords)
>   (sclang-init-document)
>   (sclang-make-document))
> ```

[Link to the commit where I fixed the issue.](https://github.com/dathinaios/spacemacs-supercollider/commit/923774f9885ce3fb7a5d500216ea1bbfea3bbfb3#diff-f40627aeb3458e3661c006ff120c8126)

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'sclang-mode "sl" 'sclang-eval-line)
```

I am using that on several of my modes and all is displayed properly.

** UPDATE **
The problem you are having is most likely because you are not creating a spacemacs layer, and instead are trying to use the traditional Emacs way of configuration.

To add this to your configuration, you need to create a custom layer. This is the `Spacemacs` way.

Have a look here for help: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/doc/LAYERS.org

Comment: That is not working I'm afraid... Am I right to assume that there must be a conflict with the package for `sclang-mode`? Is there a way to trace the problem?

Comment: @Dionysis would you please run `M-x` `spacemacs/report-issue` and paste the output in your original post? Also, is sclang-mode a custom layer you have created or is it a spacemacs included layer?

Comment: I added a bit more info in the original post. The `spacemacs/report-issue` takes me to GitHub. I did not go through to avoid creating an unnecessary report. It seems to me that this is going to end up being something for the `sclang-mode` creator to sort out and not for the `spacemacs` developers.

Comment: @Dionysis I have updated my answer. You should create a `layer`.

Comment: I finally returned to this and created the layer. It is all working well but putting the line you suggested in keybindings.el of my layer is still not registering it. When I look up the functions they are still bound to the default keys... Any ideas?

Comment: @Dionysis define your keys in your packages.el file under the init function for the package. refer to the URL I posted in answer.

Comment: I did read the docs carefully and tried everything I can I am afraid. If it turns out that it was my mistake in the layer definition I will change the right answer back to yours. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're likely right that it's an upstream bug, as was the case here:

https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/6943

Comment: I think you might be right... It is a shame that there is a gap and a package working on emacs does not always work on spacemacs. It seems that to resolve it I will have to get into `elisp`when time allows and check the source of the package.